# Hide all tr elements doesn't containing a td with a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table containing multiple line defined as follow:

```
<tr class="treegrid-1 treegrid-parent-0 trCusto" >
    <td data-column="Status" class="tdCusto cellGreen" style="text-align: center; width: 200px; " data-value="Supported">Supported</td>
    <td data-column="Reference" class="tdCusto" style="width: 100px; " data-value="123455">123455</td>
</tr>
```

With a single jquery line, i would like to hide the all `<tr>` for which we don't find a provided status value in a `<td>` element:

```
$("#myTable").find("[data-value!='"+newStatusSelected+"']").parent().hide();
```

My code doesn't works, it hide all ceils..

Comment: Why you want a single line ? any specific reason ?

Comment: It will hide the entire row as long as ONE of the cells does not match `newStatusSelected`. Perhaps that is the reason why all your rows are hidden, because they contain one or more cells whose value does not match.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because the rows that do have matching cells *also* have cells without matching values.

You can do it by combining [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to say "find me a tr that doesn't have a descendant with this `data-value`":

```
$("#myTable").find("tr:not(:has([data-value='" + newStatusSelected + "']))").hide();
```

Example:

```js
var newStatusSelected = "Supported";
$("#myTable").find("tr:not(:has([data-value='" + newStatusSelected + "']))").hide();
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="treegrid-1 treegrid-parent-0 trCusto">
      <td data-column="Status" class="tdCusto cellGreen" style="text-align: center; width: 200px; " data-value="Supported">Supported</td>
      <td data-column="Reference" class="tdCusto" style="width: 100px; " data-value="123455">123455</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-1 treegrid-parent-0 trCusto">
      <td data-column="Status" class="tdCusto cellGreen" style="text-align: center; width: 200px; " data-value="Foo">Foo</td>
      <td data-column="Reference" class="tdCusto" style="width: 100px; " data-value="123455">123455</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. Just another question : how to exclude the <tr> line which has <th> elements ? (the first line in fact)

Comment: @wawanopoulos: Remember that when you use a compound CSS selector, there's an implicit "AND" joining them up -- `div.foo` means "an element which is a div AND has the class foo". So you can have more than one `:not(:has(...))`...